# WPF : Custom Controls

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

[image]

**My Question :**
How to build custom layout for controls like above pictures ?

by Microsoft Expression Blend ? 
How ?

Please Direct me to the right article or discuss what you have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression Blend 4 has some built-in shapes that could help you out here. Basically, you want to re-template a `TextBox` control to contain the speech bubble shape instead of a standard `Border`.

Alternatively, you could do this without re-templating. Something like this:

```
<UserControl xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" Margin="100">
    <ed:Callout AnchorPoint="-0.13,0.29" CalloutStyle="RoundedRectangle" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black">
        <ed:Callout.Content>
            <TextBox BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">Hello</TextBox>
        </ed:Callout.Content>
    </ed:Callout>
</UserControl>
```

[image]

By the way, did you really mean `TextBox`, or do you actually mean `TextBlock`? If the latter, all you need is:

```
<ed:Callout AnchorPoint="-0.13,0.29" CalloutStyle="RoundedRectangle" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" Content="Hello"/>
```

Comment: re implement what ?   , what it the specific container to implement ?

Comment: re-template, not re-implement.